# MYSQL match id with column keywords and show results

Tags: mysql, database, match, resultset

I have a db with hundreds of cakes and different keywords for each cake. In this example what I want to achieve is to first match cakes that have at least 2 similar keywords-- in this example it would be cakes 1 and 4. (Not sure how to do a table here, but I have listed ids 1-4 and then a column called ingredients that shows three ingredients for each id.) And then I want to show them. Sounds easy enough, but I have been unsuccessful thus far. Any help is appreciated.

Table name:desserts

id             ingredients
1--              fudge, caramel, coconut--
2.              vanilla, hazelnut, coconut--
3.              vanilla, chocolate, fudge--
4.             fudge, caramel, vanilla--

Basically, I want to show all cakes that have two or more of the same ingredients. Not sure how to do the query.

Comment: What have you tried ? What is you DB schema ? If you list ingredients in a field of your "cakes" database, you're doing it very wrong...

Comment: You will have much easier time writing a query for this problem, if you didn't put comma-seperated values in your table. An ideal schema would have a separate table called 'ingredients' with a 'dessert_id' column.

Comment: All values are separated by a comma, e.g., fudge, caramel, coconut. How can I work with what I have?

Answer (score 0):

That is a really horrible database design and the correct answer is to change it.  Ideally you should have separate tables for cakes and for ingredients, then a third to relate cake ids with ingredient ids.

But assuming cakes always have three ingredients, you can, though you absolutely should not, do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM (SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(ingredients,',',1) AS ingredient FROM cakes
     UNION
     SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ingredients,',',-2),',',1) AS ingredient FROM cakes
     UNION
     SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(ingredients,',',-1) AS ingredient FROM cakes) AS i
GROUP BY ingredient
HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

It uses a sub-select to create three tables of ingredients, one for each comma separate position, which are combined as a `UNION`.  Once you have this information it is simply a case of grouping cakes by their ingredients and filtering out those ingredients which have not been used more than once (the `HAVING` clause).  This leaves you with a list of cake ids that contain non-unique ingredients.

It is a horrid solution and will not work if you have cakes with four or more ingredients, though you can add more `UNION` statements to account for more possibly ingredients if there is no way of changing the database design.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this and the correct way (three tables). I just wasn't sure how to do the third table that relates cake ids with ingredient ids

Comment: did you mean to write "AS ingredient FROM cakes) AS i"? near the end?

Comment: I did. The `AS ingredient FROM cakes` is just the conclusion to the `SELECT` statement, the `)` is to close the subselect (matching the `(` after `FROM`), finally the `AS i` is because when you build a table in a subselect you need to assign it an alias.  Normally you would be joining a subselect with another table so would need  way to reference it, but even though it is not needed here MySQL will give an error without it.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael - quite right wrt three tables, cakes, ingredients and cakes_ingredients_rel.

- A cake has many ingredients
- An ingredient can be used in many cakes

This is a many to many relationship.

Therefore a relationship table is used to map cakes to ingredients:

```
CAKES_INGREDIENTS_REL
id
cakes_id
ingredients_id
```